# Run an *.exe application via form, then show the form again upon app exit

Tags: vb6, exe

So I recently got stuck in my VB6 programming where I tried to make the form reappear once more after it's hidden while running an *.exe application.

This form has only one button that would open an *.exe, and upon button click, the program in question opens and the form is hidden. Once the program in question is closed, the form should reappear though in my condition it doesn't. The following is the code for the button itself:

```
Private Sub btnClicky_Click()
Dim Res
Dim Filename
Filename = "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"
    Res = Shell(Filename, vbHide)

If IsProcessRunning("Notepad.exe") Then
    Me.Hide
Else
    Me.Show
End If
End Sub
```

Once it works, I would implement the code to the assignment I am working as I am currently in an office internship program and I had to create a user interface program which involves linking multiple applications. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way would be to shell the application, hide your app & wait for the process to terminate:

```
Private Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000
Private Const WAIT_INFINITE = -1&
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Private Sub btnClicky_Click()
   Dim hProcess As Long

   hProcess = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, True, Shell("notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus))

   Me.Hide

   Call WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, WAIT_INFINITE)
   Call CloseHandle(hProcess)

   Me.Show
   Me.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is executed only if the button is clicked ,i propose that you insert a timer in your form and in the event of "Timer1_Timer" when you maust do you test :

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
If IsProcessRunning("Notepad.exe") Then
    Me.Hide
Else
    Me.Show
End If
End Sub
```